# How can i make banner text in back of the navbar

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the navbar using a media query that can be opened and closed and when I open the navbar, the text on the banner suddenly arrives in front of the navbar. I use "Display: block;" but nothing happened, please help me!

---

### this is the code inside the media query

```
    .menu a {
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .hide-menu-btn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 24px;
        right: 23px;
    }
    #chk:checked ~ .menu {
        right: 0;
    }
    .upload{
  border-radius: 50px;
        height: 40;
        width: 80;
    }
    .hero{
    height: 700px;
            display: block

        }
        .n{
            font-size: 36px;
            display: block;
            z-index: 1;

        }
```

Comment: Share the html and css as snippet. So that we can easily debug it.

Comment: Could you please share the html code as well?